# php function returning value for some pages, but fails to return values for other pages with same document structure

Tags: php, jquery

So here I want to get an ID for the specific user, using a php page, and then perform database insert using a function defined in a file named 'functions.php'. So basically, I am capturing values from a page using jQuery ajax() method and sending the data to a php page named 'follow_school.php'. The rest of what's happening would be clear from the code, I provide below:

**jQuery code**:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var school_name = jQuery('#school-name').text();
    var session_var = jQuery('#session').text();
    // console.log(session_var);
    var button_text_onload = 
    localStorage.getItem("btnText_"+school_name+"_for_"+session_var);
    console.log(button_text_onload);
    if (button_text_onload !== null) {
        jQuery('#follow-button').html(button_text_onload);
    } else {
        jQuery('#follow-button').html('Follow');
    }
    jQuery('#follow-button').click(function() {
        // alert (session_var);
        // console.log(session_var);
        var button_text = jQuery('#follow-button').text();
        // alert(button_text);
        if (button_text === 'Follow') { 
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 
         'https://mim-insider.com/wp-content/themes/Divi/follow_school.php',
                data: {name : school_name,
                      email : session_var
                },
                success: function(result) {
                    console.log(result);
                    var key = "btnText_" + school_name +"_for_" + 
                               session_var;
                    console.log(key);
                    localStorage.setItem(key, "Unfollow");
                jQuery('#follow-button').html('Unfollow');
            }});
        } else {
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url:
       'https://mim-insider.com/wp-content/themes/Divi/unfollow_school.php',
                data: {name : school_name,
                       email : session_var,
                },
                success: function(result) {
                    console.log(result);
                    var key = "btnText_" + school_name +"_for_" + 
                               session_var;
                    console.log(key);
                    localStorage.setItem(key, "Follow");
                jQuery('#follow-button').html("Follow");
            }});
        }
    });
});
```

**follow_school.php**

```
<?php   
    include_once "includes/db.php";
    include_once "includes/functions.php";

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $id = get_id($email);

    /* for debugging purpose */
    if ($id == null) {
        var_dump($id);
    } else {
        echo $id;
    }
    echo $email;

    /* insert operation */
    insert_school($id, $name);
?>
```

**functions.php**

```
function get_id($email) {
    global $conn;

    $sql = "SELECT id FROM member WHERE email = '$email'";

    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

    return $row["id"];
}

function insert_school($id, $name) {
    global $conn;

    $sql = "INSERT INTO user_schools (user_id, school_name)
    VALUES ('$id', '$name')";

    $conn->query($sql);
}
```

**NOTE**: Here the database connection is perfectly fine, and these codes worked for some pages earlier. But apparently, other pages don't seem to run the code, or to be precise, returns "null" as id. Also, I would like to mention that, the table entries and fields are not null, or unspecified. They are perfectly fine, as I said, it worked for some pages.

Please can anyone guide me, as to what's going wrong here, because after dedicating so much of my time on this, i still am not able to understand the issue.
Thank you.

Comment: Do the pages that the code does not work on have anything in common (or better yet do they have something distinctly different from the pages that do work)? Are all the pages in the same directory?

Comment: @Doug, the pages are identical with just the title changed in the <h1> tag, and the pages are created using WordPress. The <h1> tag has id="school-name", which is captured by jQuery on document load. Apart from that, it has a button with same id for all pages.